# Block layer switch for protocol specific drivers

Tags: linux-kernel, filesystems, storage, inode, block-device

I am learning the mysterious block layer, I tried to hook into the **generic_make_request** function and see for which block device is the request belong to.

In my case, I have a /dev/sda scsi device, I can see the direction READ | WRITE, and other details of the request.

I now wanted to search deeper into this block request, as to how does the kernel decide which device specific driver should handle a request.

For example if I had 2 devices a scsi and a IDE, I would have 2 block devices, /dev/sda and /dev/hd0.

Where exactly will the switching from the generic block layer happen to the device or protocol specific layer (scsi.c and ide.c), what information is used.

Comment: Where is generic_block_request function?

Comment: sorry generic_make_request function